# Vb.Net Async XML Writing?

Tags: xml, vb.net, asynchronous, io

I have a subroutine which checks an XML file for duplicates and either replaces them or writes a new one.

Rough example:

```
  Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
        doc.Load("xmlfile.xml")
 Dim node As XmlNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Listing", "")

   Dim MatchNamenode As XmlNode = doc.CreateElement("ListName") 'set a node
        MatchNamenode.InnerText = NewMatchName 'give it a value
        node.AppendChild(MatchNamenode) 'stick it in a parent

 doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(node)
        doc.Save("xmlfile.xml")
```

Works just fine. But if I'm multi-threading and make this routine Async will that cause some kind of I/O access issue?

The different threads would be passing unique information so there's no issue with the results overlapping. But if one thread is saving the XML file might that prevent another from accessing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to multithread the processing, then yes you could have file locks from one thread saving and blocking the access.

You have a couple of options:

1. Read in the data to memory and operate on the in memory information, then perform saving at the end with a single thread.
2. Batch the files that you want to work with into different sets, and hand each set off to a task. You would ensure that no batch contains a reference to the same file as another batch.